# Is it possible to add tabs inside another tabs in android?

Tags: android, tabs

I have an application which have 3 tabs on the top, I want inside the second tab to add another 5 tabs on the bottom.

is that possible? if yes can you show how?

Comment: Advice, for the love of your users, don't. Nested tabs are right up there with nested scroll bars.

Comment: @ Andrew White , what do you mean in nested scroll bars ?

Comment: find a webpage that is "tall" and that has an input box that is also "tall" and both will have scroll bars. Wordpress admin at one time was a good example